# Service 'tomcat7' is missing the ImageFile

Tags: windows-server-2003, tomcat

I am trying to run the Tomcat as a service on and Windows server.  If I run tomcat7.exe in the bin directory, I get the error "Service 'tomcat7' is missing the ImageFile".  If I run startup.bat, tomcat opens in a new window and works just fine.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and could find a workaround. I don't know if it will work for you, though, since the OS is different (Windows Server 2008).

Steps:

1. First delete the tomcat service with "bin\tomcat7.exe //DS/Tomcat7".
2. Now, disable UAC.
3. Install the Tomcat service again with the command "bin\service.bat install"
4. Start the service.
5. If you want (and probably will), enable UAC again.

Since I successfully installed and started the Tomcat service, I did not need to disable UAC again.

The advice to disable UAC is present Tomcat 7 documentation, located at "http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html"